# Graph Library API design

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am writing my own Graph library [Graph++](http://code.google.com/p/graphplusplus/source/browse/Graph/src/Graph.h), I have question regarding what should interface return. For example What should my `BFS` return, I am confuse on the point that whether it should return set of `vertices` visited in the order , or should I have `callback function`, which will get invoked during each visit.

What could be the best option so that my library will easily consumable.

Comment: Please take a look at Boost Graph Library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Comment: Hint: your include guards are invalid identifiers. C++ names must not start with an underscore followed by a capital letter. Best to avoid leading underscores generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recurring pattern in the stl is to offer iterators.  Your traversal algorithms might return a start iterator, and the library user could increment it as desired, while comparing against an `end()` iterator that either it or the graph provides.

The [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) may also be relevant to your interests.

Comment: +1 for visitor pattern, which would be useful in breadth-first traversal. For breadth-first *search*, maybe returning a matching node would be useful.

Comment: Prefer functional approach to iterative, IMO.

Comment: Yea, I also like functional style a lot.  I just don't trust my own opinions to reflect the majority of C++ developers.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t want to be unhelpful or sound arrogant. This is just a personal opinion and you should take it for what it is worth. You did not say why you are writing this library, so I’ll assume you have a specific problem to solve. If you are doing it just for fun or to learn, please go ahead and disregard the reminder of this reply.

Graphs are extremely generic abstractions. Any data structure more complex than a tree is a graph. Most programs have such data structures. For example, a web site containing linked pages is a graph. So is a representation of a map. However, when you think of these as graphs, you ignore all differences between web sites and street maps and focus on the only thing that it is common.

In the vast majority of cases, the details you are trying to abstract away, the fact that web pages are HTML, links are URLs, streets have speed limits, intersections have traffic lights, and so on, are more important. If you start your implementation with a graph abstraction, by the time you implement these other details on top of it you’ve got yourself into quite a mess. It is much better to start with other, more important abstractions as building blocks and connect those together to form a graph. Sure, you won’t get the shortest path algorithm for free for your street map, for example, but you are likely interested in the fastest route anyway, for which you need speed limits, traffic lights, and other information.

I guess what I’m trying to say is that I see very limited uses for a generic graph library. It is nice that we have the Boost Graph Library, but AFAIK, not many people are using it.

Comment: this exercise is to learn graph algorithms and try making library as generic as possible

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, prefer functional approach to iterative. In C++03, use iterator strategies.